# How Solutions can be emailed directly to case contacts?

Tags: apex, community, service-cloud-console, servicecloud

I want to send solutions with attachments directly to case contacts for common case issues.
Cay any one please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an email template and look Case (note Case not Solutions) fields you will see some Solution fields with * against them:

[image]

Basically add the merge fields {!Case.Solution_Subject} and {!Case.Solution_Description} to the email template:

[image]

Then create your Solution:

[image]

attach it to your Case:
[image]

then when emailing from the Case select the template:
[image]